# write html content into word and download in user machine using node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, html-pdf

How to use `html-docx-js` in `node.js` .

I have refered the npm site (https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-docx-js) for this. Below is the code

```
var converted = htmlDocx.asBlob(content);
saveAs(converted, 'test.docx');
```

But here is the problem, the `saveAs` function is missing in the tutorial.

I have downloaded `filesaver.js` on the client side i Iave implemented this and it works fine. But I want complete code in `node.js` running which it will convert my html content and will download a word file in client machine.

Looking forward for some help.
Regards,

Bikram Nayak.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please remove your email and add the smallest possible section of your code which you are having a problem with

Answer (score 0):

```
    var HtmlDocx = require('html-docx-js');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var html = 'fasfasfasdfsfsdfsf';

    var docx = HtmlDocx.asBlob(html);
    fs.writeFile('helloworld3.docx',docx, function (err){
       if (err) return console.log(err);
       console.log('done');
    });
```